# operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue for spring amqp

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I've two applications using the same `spring-amqp` and `spring-cloud-stream` configuration. However, when one of the rabbitmq cluster node goes down, one application is redeclaring anonymous queues while the second one fails. The only difference I found in the logs is additional boolean value in the amqqueue log. The whole declaration during the application startup works as a charm. The only issue is when the rabbitmq node on which the queue is registered is shutdown.

== WORKING APPLICATION ==

```
spring: Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (myQueueName.anonymous.A6dm37UlRsisaftuN8SwkQ) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.

rabbit: 2019-08-13 00:27:02.636 [debug] <0.1241.0> Supervisor {<0.1241.0>,rabbit_amqqueue_sup} started rabbit_prequeue:start_link({amqqueue,{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"myQueueName.anonymous.A6dm37UlRsisaftuN8SwkQ">>},false,...}, declare, <0.1240.0>) at pid <0.1242.0>
```

== FAILING APPLICATION ==

```
spring: Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (myQueueName.anonymous.-6He5tcQSB2Bk17EIiay3g) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.

rabbit: 2019-08-13 00:24:07.097 [debug] <0.2922.0> Supervisor {<0.2922.0>,rabbit_amqqueue_sup} started rabbit_prequeue:start_link({amqqueue,{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"myQueueName.anonymous.-6He5tcQSB2Bk17EIiay3g">>},false,true,...}, declare, <0.2921.0>) at pid <0.2923.0>

rabbit: operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue 'myQueueName.anonymous.-6He5tcQSB2Bk17EIiay3g' in vhost '/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another reason for this issue if you set `passive` flag for `queue_declare` method:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.passive

It expects that someone already created a queue.
Unset the flag or create a queue with other component of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've realized the difference between those two applications is that the first one is the consumer as well as the producer. If the application is just a consumer and it does not contain producer definition, the exchange redeclaration handled by spring during the broker restart fails (even if the exchange is properly registered on the node before this operation). Setting `declareExchange=false` in the consumer properties resolved the issue.

Comment: I am not sure why not declaring the exchange would help. There was a [recent fix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/pull/246) (in 2.1.3) to ensure that auto-delete queues are always created on the node we are connected to. With earlier versions, you can do the same by adding a `Master Locator` policy (`client-local`) that matches the anonymous queue names.

Comment: @GaryRussell I cannot understand it as well. We use 2.1.3 and the problem still occurs. After playing with consumer properties we found Rabbit during the queue recreation is throwing an exception that for example `inequivalent arg 'durable' for exchange`, even as the exchange exists. If the exchange properties were exactly the same as in the producer, the queue recreation always failed with the `operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found` even if all our queues were using client-local policy